# $.when().done() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing the some issue with $.when().done() functions with jQuery. Can anyone help please? When I have ajax calls and non-ajax call methods, non-ajax call is calling even I use $.when().done(). See below snippet. Method/function three is running before.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Initial();
});

function Initial() {
    debugger;
    var emp = { Name: "Ram", Age: 10 };
    Main(emp);
}

function Main(em) {
    $.when(One(em)).done(Two(em)).done(Three(em.Name));
}

function One(et) {
    //some ajax call
    console.log("One");
}

function Two(et) {
    //some ajax call
    console.log("Two");
}

function Three(et) {
    console.log(et);//not an ajax call
    console.log("Three");
}
```

**Edit:**

Below is the code snippet after the modifications by Vohuman, which is working like a charm

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        Initial();
    });

    function Initial() {
        debugger;
        var emp = { Name: "Ram", Age: 10 };
        Main(emp);
    }

    function Main(em) {
        var def1 = $.Deferred();
        var def2 = $.Deferred();
        One(em, def1);
        Two(em, def2);
        $.when(def1, def2).done(function () {
            Three(em.Name)
        });
    }

    function One(et, defObj) {
        //some ajax call
        if (defObj) {
            defObj.resolve();
        }
        console.log("One");
    }

    function Two(et, defObj) {
        //some ajax call
        if (defObj) {
            defObj.resolve();
        }
        console.log("Two");
    }

    function Three(et) {
        console.log(et);//not an ajax call
        console.log("Three");
    }
```

Comment: console log values are returning fine and i am not seeing error.Could you please paste the complete error message if you are observing from your end?

Comment: @ Naga Sai A, I am not getting any error with the code.. but the order of the execution is not as expected. I need to execute the function Three when One & Two are completely executed.

Comment: actually you should use "then" not "done"

Comment: I got the output as 

One
Two
Ram
Three

which I think sounds right. What is the problem?

Comment: @phreakv6, If you add some ajax calls with function one & two then you can see the different outputs. With the code above it is giving expected results as three of the functions are non-ajax.

Comment: If there are ajax calls inside those functions, they do not respect the done() callbacks you have. You need to use the success callback function to invoke the next method in the chain or use async:false;

Answer (score 2):

The `()` is called Invocation Operator. It invokes a function. This means you are *calling* the function yourself and the returned value of the function is set as the *callback* and not the function itself.

```
$.when(One(em)).done(Two).done(Three);
```

And if you want to have the callback called with parameters you should use a middleware, i.e. another function.

```
function Main(em) {
    $.when(One(em)).done(function() {
       Two(em);
    }).done(function() {
       Three(em.Name);
    });
}
```

Also note that if you want send several ajax requests and have a callback executed when all of them are complete, you can pass several deferred objects to `$.when`:

```
$.when(deferredOne, deferredTwo).then(function(resolvedValueOne, resolvedValueTwo) {

});
```

And as a suggestion, do not use PascalCase names for regular functions. By convention, in JavaScript PascalCase names are used for naming constructors and classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vohuman, I tried this way. With the change, the order of execution is like this.

Function Two()
Function Three()
Function One()

How can I make the execution in order One(), Two() & Three().

Comment: And as a suggestion, do not use PascalCase names for regular functions. By convention, in JavaScript PascalCase names are used for naming constructors and classes. - Yes, I am following camel cases with function names, for test I made names like that.. Anyway thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Buddha Yes that should be the order. The `done` callbacks are executed in the specified order. You are probably looking for the second suggested snippet in the answer. And if the second request needs data from the first request then you should send the request in the `done` handler of the first request.

Comment: with the first snippet can we make the execution in the order? I am not an expert in java script, so can you please provide some sample code with second snippet?

Comment: Currently it has an order. I think jQuery documentations can be helpful http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/. And please update your question and be  more specific regarding what you are trying achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Vohuman. I need to show the user information by selecting the drop down item, so drop down items should be filled before selecting the specific one.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vohuman. I am able to achieve the required thing with deferred.

Comment: @Buddha You are very welcome! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

another way of doing same is

```
$.when(One(em), Two(em)).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
        Three(em.Name)
       });
```

but One and Two method must return promise object.